# Using session_decode

Tags: php, session

I need to decode session data to find out if a user currently has a session.

What would be the best way to do this, using `session_decode`?

Comment: session_decode might not work as you expect it. If you don't want to fiddle with broken regexes to actually parse the whole session data but use a library instead, checkout [Serialized](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized), it supports session variables as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`session_id()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to see if there is a current session.  If there is no current session, it will return an empty string.

Comment: Hi, how would I identify the user or userid though?

Comment: Session data won't automatically include a username or user id. These are application-specific values that must be added explicitly at runtime. If you're snooping around in cruft session data left by others, see the comment above from @hakre for a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `print_r($_SESSION);` to see what session variables there are.  Then if you need to do a specific condition

```
<?php

    if ($_SESSION['userid']) {

        // Do things
    }

?>
```

eg

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['userid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'myusername';
    $_SESSION['password'] = 'mypassword';

    if ($_SESSION['username']) {

        echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to map a session to a user, so one can remotely terminate a user's session.